# Need help understanding some Flow type syntax

Tags: flowtype, relayjs

I’m working on porting the Flow type generator that comes with a library ([Relay](https://github.com/facebook/relay)) to one that emits TypeScript types, but have some questions about some Flow syntax that’s not obvious to me in [this snippet](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/fe0e70f10bbcba1fff89911313ea69f24569464b/packages/relay-compiler/core/__tests__/fixtures/flow-generator/typename-on-union.golden.txt#L1-L16):

```
import type { FragmentReference } from 'relay-runtime';
export opaque type TypenameInside$ref: FragmentReference = FragmentReference;
export type TypenameInside = ({|
  +__typename: 'User',
  +firstName: ?string,
  +$refType: TypenameInside$ref,
|} | {|
  +__typename: 'Page',
  +username: ?string,
  +$refType: TypenameInside$ref,
|} | {|
  // This will never be '%other', but we need some
  // value in case none of the concrete values match.
  +__typename: '%other',
  +$refType: TypenameInside$ref,
|});
```

Namely, what are `$ref`, `$refType`, and `%other`? Or are they not Flow specific, but rather Relay specific?

I tried searching the flowtype docs and repo, but had a very hard time coming up with answers. Links to the docs and/or relevant portions of the implementation would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: @halfer Done, thanks for the heads-up 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$ref`, `$refType` etc. are normal type names.

The `$` prefix for types are a convention to denote utility types such as `$Keys`, though doesn't look like the convention is followed here.

`%other` is just a normal string. Relay probably uses the string for some special purpose internally.

Comment: `$ref` is part of the variable name. The full variable name is `TypeNameInside$ref`. To the JS interpreter/flow server, there's nothing special about the `$` - it's just another character.